# Threads in java behaving in a sequential fashion

Tags: java, multithreading

I am observing a strange behavior in Java threads where they are seemingly running in a sequential fashion. Following is the code snippet

```
class ThreadUnsafeClass {

    private static int y;

    public static void incrementY() {
        y++;
    }

    public static int getY() {
        return y;
    }

}

public class MultiThreadedClass implements Runnable {
    int threadId;

    MultiThreadedClass (int threadId) {
        this.threadId = threadId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Number:"+ threadId + ";Thread Unsafe Old Value:" + ThreadUnsafeClass.getY());

        try {
            if (threadId == 1 || threadId ==2) {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        ThreadUnsafeClass.incrementY();

        System.out.println("Number:"+ threadId + ";Thread Unsafe New Value:" + ThreadUnsafeClass.getY());
    }

    public static void main (String []args) {
        MultiThreadedClass thread1 = new MultiThreadedClass(1);
        MultiThreadedClass thread2 = new MultiThreadedClass(2);
        MultiThreadedClass thread3 = new MultiThreadedClass(3);
        MultiThreadedClass thread4 = new MultiThreadedClass(4);
        thread1.run();
        thread2.run();
        thread3.run();
        thread4.run();
   }
}
```

Following is the output of the same:

```
Number:1;Thread Unsafe Old Value:0
Number:1;Thread Unsafe New Value:1
Number:2;Thread Unsafe Old Value:1
Number:2;Thread Unsafe New Value:2
Number:3;Thread Unsafe Old Value:2
Number:3;Thread Unsafe New Value:3
Number:4;Thread Unsafe Old Value:3
Number:4;Thread Unsafe New Value:4
```

From the above output, it may be noticed that even when threads 1 and 2 are waiting for a reasonable amount of time i.e. 60s threads 3 and 4 still execute only when they have finished executing. Why aren't the threads executing in parallel and when one thread sleeps, why isn't the other thread going ahead with its execution? Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: don't you mean sequential, not serialized?

Comment: You didn't start any threads.

Comment: You never actually create any threads! Instead, in one single thread, you call each object's `run` function serially!

Comment: @Gray - I am doing it purposely. Was trying to experiment on how threads are unsafe. :)

Comment: @mre - Yes, thanks for correcting me. Editing my post accordingly.

Comment: Whoops.  Of course @AbhishekJain.  Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a `Thread` referencing the `Runnable` and call `start()`, not `run()` on the actual class. Making something `Runnable` doesn't mean it's automatically going to run in a separate thread.

e.g.

```
(new Thread(myRunnable)).start()
```

Why the separation between `Runnable` and `Thread` ? I can take a `Runnable` and drop it into a thread pool. The next available thread will run that `Runnable`. (e.g. see the Java [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) framework) `Runnable` only indicates that an object is available for threading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand it completely now.

Answer (score 3):

You should extend `Thread` and call `thread.start()` instead of `thread.run()`, because `thread1.run()` calls the method synchronously. `thread.start` will call `run()` asynchronously, achieving the effect that you are looking for.

You could also construct a `Thread` from your `Runnable` using this constructor:

[`Thread(Runnable r)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: @BrianAgnew Thanks for the note, I edited the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to have a class implementing `Runnable` to run in a different thread. Instead of

```
MultiThreadedClass thread1 = new MultiThreadedClass(1);
MultiThreadedClass thread2 = new MultiThreadedClass(2);
MultiThreadedClass thread3 = new MultiThreadedClass(3);
MultiThreadedClass thread4 = new MultiThreadedClass(4);
thread1.run();
thread2.run();
thread3.run();
thread4.run();
```

try doing

```
new Thread(new MultiThreadedClass(1)).start();
new Thread(new MultiThreadedClass(2)).start();
new Thread(new MultiThreadedClass(3)).start();
new Thread(new MultiThreadedClass(4)).start();
```

Comment: @Boris - There is a slight problem in your answer. As MultiThreaded class doesn't extend Thread and only implements the Runnable Interface, you cannot assign an object of Thread Class to a variable of type MultiThreaded Class. Modifying your answer accordingly.